# Error too many rows 50001 in a custom Rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, batch, query

I have a custom rest API that when is called from a third party system (this third party system calls me providing a country code like UK, DE, US... and some other parameters) I filter account object using this parameters and send them a custom JSON formated with the information they need, this works perfect for all countries except for US, I have so much accounts created with this country code (more than 100.000) so as long as I call this API with providing US parameter I'm getting too many rows 50001 Error in the line that I query in my APEX code for these accounts. Since I can't filter more these queries, how would you face this problem guys?

EDIT:

First of all, thank you @nbrown @Phil W @cropredyy

let me explain it a bit better, I don't need to return more than 50000K results, when this process works for other countries, we are retrieving 20 or 30 results for maybe 40K accounts finded in the first query. The problem is that my very first query over account is returning, for the US country, more than 50000K results so there we have the problem, I can't filter more this query. Can i do something like this:

1.- 3rd party system call me
2.- Run a batch process or something and get all the list of accounts
3.- Send this list to an apex method, do all the filterings
4.- Create the Json with all the records that pass the filter and send this Json to the 3rd party system.

Comment: I can't imagine it's very useful for the caller to get so many results back. How are results ordered? The simplest solution is to put a `LIMIT` and [`OFFSET` on the query so the caller only gets a certain amount of results back and then can call again to get more.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm)

Comment: If you used the standard REST API for running the query then the API will automatically paginated the response data. Alternatively you could implement your own pagination in your Apex using LIMIT and the last returned record's order by values and some appropriate where clause terms to ensure already returned data is skipped. This latter is really easy if you order by ID, for example.

Comment: BTW, use of OFFSET is unlikely to work for you since the maximum offset is 2000, hence my alternative suggestions compared with that from @nbrown.

Comment: In line with Phil and nbrown; your custom Apex REST endpoint should implement a queryMore like pattern by returning a `nextRecordsUrl` value in your paginated response body (with URL param being the last recordfetched). AutoNumber fields on the recs make this easy to use and are indexed

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I've just updated the question with more information :)